# Filtering excel dates in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, date

I have a very simple line of code that works in Excel VBA, but I can't for the life of me figure out how it works in VB.NET. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & sdate
```

edit: complete code

```
 Dim sDate as Date
 Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
 sdate = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
 OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Documents | *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsxm"
 If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
 xlWB= xlapp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

 xlWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("H1").Select()
 xlapp.Selection.AutoFilter()               
 xlapp.Selection.AutoFilter(Field:=8, Criteria1:="=>" & sDate)
```

Comment: This code gives an error or the wrong filter ?

Comment: Doesn't throw an error, the filter is just blank, and no rows are selected.

Comment: I have chage you code as in answer, you can test it.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you must convert date from `DateTimePicker1` to Date format with `DateSerial`, and convert de value of date to `OLE Automation` with `ToOADate`

you must also change operator of criteria `"=>"` to `">="`, the = sign must be after.

```
Dim sDate As Date
Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim dpDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
sDate = DateSerial(dpDate.Year, dpDate.Month, dpDate.Day)
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Documents | *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsxm"
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    xlWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

    xlWB.Worksheets("Data").Range("H1").Select()
    xlapp.Selection.AutoFilter()
    xlapp.Selection.AutoFilter(Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & sDate.ToOADate)
End If
```

Comment: I have the brackets in VB.NET, but still doesn't work properly.

Comment: what is range Selection you use ?

Comment: see my edit, I've added the complete code. I suspect it has something to do with criteria in autofilter being a string? it works fine in excel though.

Comment: What is the type of data in Field 8 and what is value in criteria (sdate) ?

Comment: The column is all dates. The value of sDate is the value from a DateTimePicker input which the user selects.